# sidewaystable misplaced in twocolumn document

Tags: tables, two-column, rotating, sv-classes

I need to format an existing document to accord to the guidelines of a paper. The existing document contains a big table, contained in a `sidewaystable` environment:

```
\begin{sidewaystable}[p]
  \caption{Big table below}
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{lccccccc}
      %very wide table contents
    \end{tabular}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

This puts the table on an own page, rotated by 90 degree in the original document. But the new document is required to use the [`svjour3` document class](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/?SGWID=0-0-45-468198-0) in `twocolumn` mode. The table is placed like in the original, but the right column on the same page is filled with text which overlaps the table:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}

\usepackage[online]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[3-8]
%\begin{sidewaystable}[p]  % overlaps following text
\begin{sidewaystable*}[p]  % runs out pf page bounds instead of being centered
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabular}{lccccccc}
            \hline
            a & a & a & a & a & a & a & a \\
            b & b & b & b & b & b & b & b \\
            c & c & c & c & c & c & c & c \\
            d & d & d & d & d & d & d & d \\
            e & e & e & e & e & e & e & e \\
            f & f & f & f & f & f & f & f \\
            a & a & a & a & a & a & a & a \\
            b & b & b & b & b & b & b & b \\
            c & c & c & c & c & c & c & c \\
            d & d & d & d & d & d & d & d \\
            e & e & e & e & e & e & e & e \\
            f & f & f & f & f & f & f & f \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{threeparttable}
%\end{sidewaystable}
\end{sidewaystable*}

\lipsum[3-8]

\end{document}
```

I tried to use `\begin{sidewaystable*}`, this stops the text from overlapping the table, but at the same time causes the table to move to the right, so that half of it is cut off.

Screenshots:
With `sidewaystable*`
[image: with sidewaystable*]

With `sidewaystable` (no star)
[image: with sidewaystable (no star)]

How can I place the `sidewaystable` centered on its own page? Or are there any alternatives to `sidewaystable` that would avoid the problem?

Comment: i can't repeat this effect -- i hacked my standard 2-column rotating package test a bit but i could not stop it working properly. please provide an actual minimum example (what you offer doesn't compile), and save me the bother of searching for svjour3 by quoting a link for it (it's not on ctan that i can see).

Comment: @wasteofspace I added a working example and a link to the class (which is from the journal's publisher). I also added two screenshots of the result of the example on my installation to clarify the problem.

Comment: thanks for that; in particular the pictures make things clearer to my fuzzy old brain.  however i fear i can't work on it until tomorrow for a variety of reasons.  (you may have bumped up against an actual omission in the changes i made when i took over the package.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

the problem is that svjour3 wants whole-page floats to be at the top of
the page, whereas the latex default is middle of page.

rotating makes the controls for this available at the user interface, so
you need to add

```
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
```

in your preamble, immediately after loading the rotating package.

(doing that to your example has the required effect there...)

the change has no effect on springer's requirements for the placing
of "ordinary" full-page floats.

sorry about the time taken to provide this resolution...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! This works fine in the original document, too.

Comment: amazing ! I wish I could give you 5 up votes :-)