# sidewaystable* in two-column document - emulateapj

Tags: floats, two-column, rotating

I have a big table that I want to display sideways in an `emulateapj` document, but I get a weird result:

```
\documentclass[]{emulateapj}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\let\captionbox\relax
\usepackage[
        font            =   small,
        labelfont       =   bf,
        labelformat =   simple,
        labelsep        =   period,
        margin      =   0.25in,
    ]{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{rotating}
    \setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}

\newcommand{\fns}{}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
    \renewcommand\p@enumii{} % make \ref display only innermost label of nested list
\makeatother

%\begin{table*}
\begin{sidewaystable*}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes} \footnotesize
    \item[\dag] \label{Tbl:Src:Note:halo}       The radio source is coincident with the cluster RH.
    \item[\ddag]    \label{Tbl:Src:Note:edge}       The radio source might be coincident with the cluster RH (edge of diffuse emission).
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{longtable}{cccccccc}
    \caption{Radio sources analyzed in previous work\label{Tbl:Src}} \\
        \toprule
        {\fns(\ref{Tbl:Src:GC})} & {\fns(\ref{Tbl:Src:Name})} & {\fns(\ref{Tbl:Src:Morph})} & {\fns(\ref{Tbl:Src:FR})}
            & {\fns(\ref{Tbl:Src:Class})} & {\fns(\ref{Tbl:Src:b})} & {\fns(\ref{Tbl:Src:LOS})} & {\fns(\ref{Tbl:Src:Ref})} \\
        Cluster & Source & Morph. & FR & Class & $r_{\bot}/r_c$ & LOS & Ref. \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead
        \caption*{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
        \toprule
        {\fns(\ref{Tbl:Src:GC})} & {\fns(\ref{Tbl:Src:Name})} & {\fns(\ref{Tbl:Src:Morph})} & {\fns(\ref{Tbl:Src:FR})}
            & {\fns(\ref{Tbl:Src:Class})} & {\fns(\ref{Tbl:Src:b})} & {\fns(\ref{Tbl:Src:LOS})} & {\fns(\ref{Tbl:Src:Ref})} \\
        Cluster & Source & Morph. & FR & Class & $r_{\bot}/r_c$ & LOS & Ref. \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        \bottomrule
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule
        \insertTableNotes\\
        \captionsetup{position=bottom}
        \caption*{\fns
            \textbf{Notes.}
                The radio sources for which RM maps have been derived and analyzed in previous works, along with some of their relevant characteristics. In this work we analyzed the sources in Coma, A2065, A2142, A2199, and Ophiuchus (italicized).
                \begin{inparaenum}[(1)]
                    \item \label{Tbl:Src:GC}        Host GC name;
                    \item \label{Tbl:Src:Name}  Source name;
                    \item \label{Tbl:Src:Morph} Radio morphology: (H)T = (Head) Tail, (N/W)AT = (Narrow/Wide) Angle Tail;
                    \item \label{Tbl:Src:FR}        Fanaroff-Riley classification;
                    \item \label{Tbl:Src:Class} Source object type;
                    \item \label{Tbl:Src:b}     Impact parameter relative to X-ray center;
                    \item \label{Tbl:Src:LOS}       Line of sight position: $\infty$ = background source, $0$ = cluster member;
                    \item \label{Tbl:Src:Ref}       RM reference: 
                    \begin{inparaenum}[1.]  
                        \item \label{Tbl:Src:Ref:Bonafede2010}  \citealt{Bonafede2010};
                        \item \label{Tbl:Src:Ref:Eilek2002}     \citealt{Eilek2002};
                        \item \label{Tbl:Src:Ref:Feretti1999}       \citealt{Feretti1999};
                        \item \label{Tbl:Src:Ref:Govoni2001}    \citealt{Govoni2001};
                        \item \label{Tbl:Src:Ref:Govoni2006}    \citealt{Govoni2006};
                        \item \label{Tbl:Src:Ref:Govoni2010}    \citealt{Govoni2010};
                        \item \label{Tbl:Src:Ref:Guidetti2008}  \citealt{Guidetti2008};
                        \item \label{Tbl:Src:Ref:Perley1991}        \citealt{Perley1991};
                        \item \label{Tbl:Src:Ref:Pizzo2011}     \citealt{Pizzo2011};
                        \item \label{Tbl:Src:Ref:Taylor1993}        \citealt{Taylor1993};
                        \item \label{Tbl:Src:Ref:Taylor2001}        \citealt{Taylor2001};
                        \item \label{Tbl:Src:Ref:Taylor2002}        \citealt{Taylor2002};
                        \item \label{Tbl:Src:Ref:Vacca2010}     \citealt{Vacca2010};
                        \item \label{Tbl:Src:Ref:Vacca2012}     \citealt{Vacca2012}.
                    \end{inparaenum}
                \end{inparaenum}
            }
        \endlastfoot
        3C 129          & 3C 129            & HT    &       & galaxy            & 1.73  & $0$       & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Taylor2001}      \\
                        & 3C 129.1      &       & I     & galaxy            & 0.01  & $0$       & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Taylor2001}      \\
        A0119           & 0053-015      & NAT   &       & E             & 0.15  & $0$       & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Feretti1999}     \\
                        & 0053-016      & NAT   &       & galaxy            & 0.90  & $0$       & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Feretti1999}     \\
                        & 3C 029            &       & I     & S             & 2.83  & $0$       & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Feretti1999}     \\
        A0400           & 3C 075            & T     &       & E0                & 0.24  & $0$       & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Eilek2002}       \\
        A0401           & A401A         & NAT   &       & galaxy            & 2.93  & $0$       & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Govoni2010}      \\
                        & A401B         & HT    &       & galaxy            & 4.20  & $0$       & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Govoni2010}      \\
        A0514           & A514A         &       & II        &               & 2.63  & $\infty$      & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Govoni2001}      \\
                        & A514B2            & NAT   &       & D             & 1.48  & $0$       & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Govoni2001}      \\
                        & A514C         &       & II        &               & 4.53  & $\infty$      & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Govoni2001}      \\
                        & A514D         & T     & I     & galaxy            & 2.71  & $0$       & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Govoni2001}      \\
                        & A514E         &       &       & QSO           & 5.32  & $\infty$      & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Govoni2001}      \\
        Hydra A         & Hydra A       &       &       & galaxy            & 20.0  & $0$       & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Taylor1993}      \\
        \textit{Coma}       & 5C 04.042     &       & II        & galaxy            & 5.77  & $\infty$      & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Bonafede2010}    \\
                        & 5C 04.074\tnotex{Tbl:Src:Note:edge}
                                        &       & II        &               & 1.95  & $\infty$      & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Bonafede2010}    \\
                        & 5C 04.081\tnotex{Tbl:Src:Note:halo}
                                        & NAT   & I     & cD                & 0.87  & $0$       & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Bonafede2010}    \\
                        & 5C 04.085\tnotex{Tbl:Src:Note:halo}
                                        & WAT   & I-II  & cD                & 0.40  & $0$       & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Bonafede2010}    \\
                        & 5C 04.114\tnotex{Tbl:Src:Note:edge}
                                        &       & I     &               & 2.04  & $\infty$      & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Bonafede2010}    \\
                        & 5C 04.127     &       &       & QSO           & 3.66  & $\infty$      & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Bonafede2010}    \\
                        & 5C 04.152     &       & II        & galaxy            & 6.68  & $\infty$      & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Bonafede2010}    \\
        \textit{A2065}      & A2065A            &       & II        & galaxy            & 1.96  & $\infty$      & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Govoni2010}      \\
        \textit{A2142}      & A2142A            & HT    & I     & galaxy            & 2.66  & $0$       & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Govoni2010}      \\
        \textit{A2199}      & 3C 338            &       & I     & cD2           & 0.05  & $\infty$      & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Vacca2012}       \\
        A2255           & Double\tnotex{Tbl:Src:Note:edge}
                                        & HT    &       & galaxy            & 2.98  &           & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Pizzo2011}       \\
                        & Goldfish\tnotex{Tbl:Src:Note:halo}
                                        & NAT   &       & galaxy            & 1.72  &           & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Pizzo2011}       \\
                        & TRG\tnotex{Tbl:Src:Note:halo}
                                        & NAT   &       & galaxy            & 1.03  &           & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Pizzo2011}       \\
                        & Bean          & HT    &       & galaxy            & 11.6  &           & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Pizzo2011}       \\
                        & Embryo            & WAT   &       &               & 7.93  &           & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Pizzo2011}       \\
                        & Beaver            & NAT   &       & galaxy            & 4.33  &           & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Pizzo2011}       \\
                        & F1, F2, F3\tnotex{Tbl:Src:Note:halo}
                                        &       &       & filaments     &       &           & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Pizzo2011}       \\
                        & J1712.4+6401\tnotex{Tbl:Src:Note:halo}
                                        &       &       &               & 0.78  &           & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Govoni2006}      \\
                        & J1713.3+6347  &       &       &               & 4.35  &           & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Govoni2006}      \\
                        & J1713.5+6402\tnotex{Tbl:Src:Note:edge}
                                        &       &       &               & 3.05  &           & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Govoni2006}      \\
                        & J1715.1+6402  &       &       &               & 8.14  &           & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Govoni2006}      \\
        A2382           & PKS 2149-158 A    &       & I     & E             & 0.44  & $0$       & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Guidetti2008}    \\
                        & PKS 2149-158 B    &       & I     & E             & 0.41  & $0$       & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Guidetti2008}    \\
                        & PKS 2149-158 C    &       & I     & E             & 0.15  & $0$       & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Guidetti2008}    \\
        A2634           & 3C 465            & T     & I     & cD                & 0.39  & $0$       & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Eilek2002}       \\
        Centaurus           & PKS 1246-410  &       & I     & cD1           & 0.34  & $0$       & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Taylor2002}      \\
        \textit{Ophiuchus}  & OPHIB         & HT    & I     & galaxy            & 2.50  & $0$       & \ref{Tbl:Src:Ref:Govoni2010}      \\
\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{sidewaystable*}
%\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The line after loading the `rotating` package in the preamble is taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47728/sidewaystable-misplaced-in-twocolumn-document).
How can I fix this?

Comment: another issue here is that the bottom caption should be left aligned and without the "TABLE 1", and I don't know why this happens.

Comment: A `longtable` doesn't work inside a `sidewaystable` environment. For workarounds see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44221/is-there-something-like-sidewayslongtable

Comment: I didn't actually need to use longtable, but was hoping that somehow I could combine two upright tables into one big sidewaystable which fits in one page. Apparently it would be too big anyway, so now I'm not using any of the table-related packages.

Comment: There is also a problem using the caption or subcaption package with emulateapj

Comment: The example doesn't compile cleanly and there's not real indication of _what_ is 'weird' in the result. Please cut down the demo to a minimum which runs (or gives an error you describe) and give an image or text description of the issue.