# Problem about table rotating

Tags: tables, rotating

Compare the the following sideways table, once with class `svjour3` and once with class `article`. Why is the table squashed to the left border when using `svjour3`? What is the best way to correct it?

[image][image]

```
%\documentclass{svjour3}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{Your caption here}
\tabcolsep=2pt
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccccc}
    \hline
    &   &   1&  2&  3&  4&  5&  6&  7&  8&  9&  10  &11&    12& 13\\
\hline
1&  Physical&   1&  &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
\hline
2&  Psychological&.8sdf*&1& &   &   &   &   &   &   & & & &  \\             
\hline
3&  Relationships&  .75345**&   .8435**&    1&&&&&&&&&&\\                                       
\hline
4&  Environment&      .459**&   .53453**&   .481**& 1&  &&&&&&&&\\                  
\hline
5&  Autonomy&     .472**&   .53345*&    .4235**&    .272**& 1&&&&&&&&\\     \hline                      
6&  Competence&   .821**&   .935345**   &.838**&    .525**& .531**& 1&&&&&&&\\  \hline                      
7&  Relatedness&     .778**&    345918**&   .800**& .512**& .531**& .902**& 1&&&&&&\\                       
\hline
8&  Secure  &.423**&    .478**& 43531**&    .300**& .251**& .455**& .427**& 1&&&&&\\                    
\hline
9&  Avoidant&   -.147*& 34588&  -.345233&   .009&   34587&  -.030&  -.091&  -.047&  1&&&&\\             
\hline
10& Ambivalent& 3456**& -.845**&    -.745**&    34535**&    -.480**&    -.839**&    -.798**&    -.446**&    .147*&  1&&&\\          
\hline
11& Immature&   -.588**&    -.663**&    -.595**&    -.4345**&   -.420**&    -.663**&    -.624**&    -.292**&    .023&   .572**& 1&&\\       
\hline
12& Mature  &.681**&    .762**& .707**& .475**& .440**& .753**& .737**& .409**& -.051&  -.666**&    -.499**&    1&\\    
\hline
13& Neurotic&   -.345**&    -.345*&43562**& -.282**&    -.266**&    -.487**&    -.462**&    -.282**&    .345&   .406**& .345**& -.405**&    1\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please reduce your document to the minimal versio n that has this issue. Especially the inclusion of the `.eps` file is not necessary here for your problem. You're trying to squeeze 15 columns with a lot of numbers into the `\linewidth` of your document, that's too much

Comment: Why is this thought to be about rotating text in a table? If you typeset the table you will see that is not the problem or a conceivable solution. It's just a crazy long table with too many columns to fit nicely on the page. Rotating text won't help!.

Comment: Your question is close related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47728/sidewaystable-misplaced-in-twocolumn-document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic problem is solved (and explained) in answer to question [problem-about-table-rotating](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47728/sidewaystable-misplaced-in-twocolumn-document).

*Off-topic:*
I would redesign table as follows:

- use `siunitx` for formatting columns with numbers, In this I would make exception for huge integer numbers)
- use rounding capabilities of `siunitx` package in round numbers to three decimals
- use `booktabs`' rules for making table looks more "professional"

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}%svjour3
\usepackage{rotating}
%\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaystable}%
\caption{Your caption here}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
%   \small
\begin{tabular}{r l 
                S[table-format=-1.3,
                  table-space-text-post={sdf*},
                  table-align-text-post=false,
                  table-auto-round]
          *{11}{S[table-format=-1.3,
                  table-space-text-post={**},
                  table-align-text-post=false,
                  table-auto-round]}
                S[table-format=1.0]
                }
    \toprule
    &               & 1         & 2             &  3        &  4        &  5        &  6    &  7&  8&  9&  10  &11&    12& 13\\
\midrule
1   & Physical      & 1         &               &           &           &           &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
%\hline
2   & Psychological &  .8sdf*   & 1             &           &           &           &   &   &   & & & &  \\
%\hline
3   & Relationships &  .75345** &  .8435**      &    1      &           &           &&&&&&&&\\
%\hline
4   & Environment   &  .459**   &  .53453**     &  .481**   & 1         &           &&&&&&&&\\
%\hline
5   & Autonomy      &  .472**   &  .53345*      &  .4235**  & .272**    & 1         &&&&&&&&\\     
%\hline
6   & Competence    &  .821**   &  .935345**    &  .838**   & .525**    & .531**    & 1         &           &           &&&&&\\  
%\hline
7   & Relatedness   &  .778**   &  {345918**}   &  .800**   & .512**    & .531**    &  .902**   & 1         &           &&&&&\\
%\hline
8   & Secure        &  .423**   &  .478**       & {43531**} & .300**    & .251**    &  .455**   & .427**    & 1         &&&&&\\
%\hline
9   & Avoidant      & -.147*    & {34588}       & -.345233  & .009      & {34587}   & -.030     & -.091     & -.047     & 1     &&&&\\
%\hline
10  & Ambivalent    & {3456**}  &  -.845**      & -.745**   & {34535**} & -.480**   & -.839**   & -.798**   & -.446**   &  .147*&  1        &&&\\
%\hline
11  & Immature      & -.588**   & -.663**       & -.595**   & -.4345**  & -.420**   & -.663**   & -.624**   & -.292**   &  .023 &  .572**   & 1   &&\\
%\hline
12  & Mature        &  .681**   &    .762**     & .707**    &  .475**   &  .440**   & .753**    & .737**    &  .409**   & -.051 & -.666**   &    -.499** & 1 &\\
%\hline
13  & Neurotic      & -.345**   &    -.345*     & {43562**} & -.282**   & -.266**   & -.487**   & -.462**   & -.282**   &  .345 &  .406**   & .345**  & -.405**   &  1\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```