# Landscape table overlapping with first column of next page

Tags: rotating, sidewaystable, overlap

I am a beginner in Latex and finding it very difficult to handle the table (compared to MS Word). So I need some guidance from the experts here.
I am trying to write a paper using springer template ([Download the template here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OloWtqT5bTmDFnUHOMipG7b9qxxz5Sv-/view?usp=sharing))\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}. I like to include a comparison table in landscape mode on a fresh page. However, when I am compiling it, the table moves to the next page trying to occupy the first column of the next page garbling everything[image: Screenshot]. I tried to use \pagebreak[4] with no effect. I am giving the MWC that I could make with my beginner's knowledge. Any alteration, smart look will be thankfully acknowledged along with the solution of the main problem.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{Comparison among state of the art designs}
\label{tab:1}       % Give a unique label
\begin{tabular}{p{1in}|p{0.5in}ccp{0.5in}p{0.5in}p{0.8in}p{1.7in}}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\textbf{Reference}&\textbf{Sensors}&\textbf{Dedicated}&\textbf{Number of sensors}&\textbf{Method}&\textbf{Accuracy}&\textbf{Features}&\textbf{Limitations}\\
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}\\

Er and Tan (2018)&Sound sensor, accelerometer&Yes&More than one&Non-ambulatory&~92\%&Fuzzy logic based dual detection capability&Indoor only, no location information, costly and non-portable solution.\\

He et al.(2020)&RFID and Radar&Yes&More than one&Non-ambulatory&~94\%&Increased detection area up to 230\% compared to traditional systems.&Indoor only, no location information, costly and non-portable solution. Implementation requires specialized training.\\

Van Thanh et al.(2018)&Proprietary accelerometer&Yes&One&Wearable sensor&~92\%&Fall as well as post fall posture recognition.&Costly and bulky, no local processing on device, no text based warning SMS.\\

Zhang, Hongtao et al.(2020)&Accelerometer, Gyroscope and Magnetometer&Yes&More than one&Wearable
sensor&~96\%&Fall and post fall posture recognition. Warning SMS with location.&Costly and bulky, no local processing on device, no text based warning SMS.\\

Zurbuchen, N. et al.(2021)&Accelerometer Gyroscope&Yes&More than one&Wearable sensor&~97\%&Multiclass fall and ADL detection.&  High initial cost, separate device, no local processing on device.\\
Yu, Gong, and Kollias (2017)&Camera&Yes&More than one&Image and computer vision&~96\%&Posture based detection ( Laying is treated as fall).&High initial cost, no local processing on device, not suitable for outdoor, privacy issues.\\

Juang et al.(2015)&Camera&Yes&More than one&Image and computer vision&100\%&Human joint identification along with fall.&High initial cost, no local processing on device,low portability, not suitable for outdoor, privacy issues. No local dataset used.\\

Zhang et al.(2020)& Camera& Yes&More than one&Image and computer vision& ~98\%&Fall detection based on body posture, local dataset used.&High initial cost, no local processing on device, not suitable for outdoor.\\

Shu, Francy. et al.(2021)&Camera&Yes&More than one& Image and computer vision&94\%&Multi genre fall detection using eight cameras.&High initial cost,low portability, no local processing on device, not suitable for outdoor, privacy issues.\\

\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Please help.

Comment: sidewaystable has ro fit in a single oage.column you columd  perhaps use `\small` or a smaller size before the tabular

Comment: sidewaystable  is just one of the solutions I have tried. Any other solution is welcome.

Comment: You might want to use `sidewaystable*` instead of `sidewaystable`. Additionally, I suggest adjusting the column widths according to their contents in order to save space and to reduce the amount of wasted white space. I'd also try to abbraviate the entries in column 4 by using "1"  and ">1" instead of the current entries.

Comment: Too geek for me. It will be very helpful if you can tell where exactly in my code those should be done. Pardon my ignorance.

Comment: Which of the suggestions are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following based on combining `sidewaystable*` with a workaround to use sidewaystable in combination with `svjour3` [from here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47879/134144).

Additionally, I also used horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package, `tabularx` to make sure the table uses all of the textblock's width, `\thead` from `makecell` for the column headers. I also intruduced some abbreviations and switched up some column lengths in order to reduce the amount of wasted white space.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable*}

\caption{Comparison among state of the art designs}
\label{tab:1}       % Give a unique label
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1in}
                             >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.75in}
                             c
                             c
                             >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.75in}
                             c
                             >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.5in}
                             X}
\toprule
\thead{Reference}&\thead{Sensors}&\thead{Dedic.}&\thead{No. of\\ sensors}&\thead{Method}&\thead{Acc. \\ in \%}&\thead{Features}&\thead{Limitations}\\
\midrule\\

Er and Tan (2018) 
  & Sound sensor, accelerometer
    & Yes & $>1$ & Non-ambulatory & 92 
      & Fuzzy logic based dual detection capability 
        & Indoor only, no location information, costly and non-portable solution.\\
\addlinespace

He et al.(2020) 
  & RFID and Radar 
    & Yes & $>1$ & Non-ambulatory & 94 
      &Increased detection area up to 230\% compared to traditional systems.
        &Indoor only, no location information, costly and non-portable solution. Implementation requires specialized training.\\
\addlinespace

Van Thanh et al.(2018)
  & Proprietary accelerometer
    & Yes & 1 & Wearable sensor & 92 
      &Fall as well as post fall posture recognition. 
        &Costly and bulky, no local processing on device, no text based warning SMS.\\ 
\addlinespace

Zhang, Hongtao et al.(2020)
  &Accelerometer, Gyroscope and Magnetometer
    & Yes & $>1$ & Wearable sensor & 96
      & Fall and post fall posture recognition. Warning SMS with location.
        &Costly and bulky, no local processing on device, no text based warning SMS.\\
\addlinespace

Zurbuchen, N. et al.(2021)
  & Accelerometer Gyroscope 
    & Yes & $>1$ & Wearable sensor & 97
      & Multiclass fall and ADL detection.
        & High initial cost, separate device, no local processing on device.\\
\addlinespace

Yu, Gong, and Kollias (2017)
  & Camera
    & Yes & $>1$ & Image and computer vision & 96
      & Posture based detection (Laying is treated as fall).
        & High initial cost, no local processing on device, not suitable for outdoor, privacy issues.\\
\addlinespace

Juang et al.(2015)
  & Camera
    & Yes & $>1$ & Image and computer vision & 100
      & Human joint identification along with fall.
        & High initial cost, no local processing on device,low portability, not suitable for outdoor, privacy issues. No local dataset used.\\
\addlinespace

Zhang et al.(2020)
  & Camera
    & Yes & $>1$ & Image and computer vision & 98 &
      Fall detection based on body posture, local dataset used.
        & High initial cost, no local processing on device, not suitable for outdoor.\\ 
\addlinespace

Shu, Francy. et al.(2021)
  & Camera
    & Yes & $>1$ & Image and computer vision & 94
      & Multi genre fall detection using eight cameras.
        & High initial cost,low portability, no local processing on device, not suitable for outdoor, privacy issues.\\

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you all for enlightening me.

Comment: Everything is fine except my table is coming 180° opposite to your shown output (Table labels on the right hand side). Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Bukaida: Did you compile the code twice?

Comment: I am using winedt10 with miktek as backend. As winedt10 automatically does all the necessary compilations and linking so that should not be the problem. I also have texlive in another machine, will give it a try today and let you know the outcome.

Comment: Nope, still the same rotated output. Is it possible to control/change the rotation by any means?

Comment: Seems like problem with the default behaviour of "rotating" package for even and odd pages. After various trial and error (including using [counterclockwise] option with rotating, the problem could be fixed by using \usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}

Answer (score 1):

This may give you are startm as you may see soe rewording of the headings eg Accuracy would help, and some of the comments under the question. Basically I just used `\small` and adjusted some of the column widths.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{graphicx,array}
    \usepackage{rotating}
\newcommand\hd[1]{\bfseries\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable*}
\caption{Comparison among state of the art designs}
\label{tab:1=zzz}       % Give a unique label (dont use numbers)
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{
@{}
>{\raggedright}p{1in}
>{\raggedright}p{1in}
cc
>{\raggedright}p{1in}
>{\raggedright}p{.8in}
>{\raggedright}p{1.5in}
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.7in}
@{}}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\textbf{Reference}&\textbf{Sensors}&\textbf{Dedicated}&\hd{Number of\\sensors}&\textbf{Method}&\textbf{Accuracy}&\textbf{Features}&\textbf{Limitations}\\
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}\\

Er and Tan (2018)&Sound sensor, accelerometer&Yes&More than one&Non-ambulatory&~92\%&Fuzzy logic based dual detection capability&Indoor only, no location information, costly and non-portable solution.\\

He et al.(2020)&RFID and Radar&Yes&More than one&Non-ambulatory&~94\%&Increased detection area up to 230\% compared to traditional systems.&Indoor only, no location information, costly and non-portable solution. Implementation requires specialized training.\\

Van Thanh et al.(2018)&Proprietary accelerometer&Yes&One&Wearable sensor&~92\%&Fall as well as post fall posture recognition.&Costly and bulky, no local processing on device, no text based warning SMS.\\

Zhang, Hongtao et al.(2020)&Accelerometer, Gyroscope and Magnetometer&Yes&More than one&Wearable
sensor&~96\%&Fall and post fall posture recognition. Warning SMS with location.&Costly and bulky, no local processing on device, no text based warning SMS.\\

Zurbuchen, N. et al.(2021)&Accelerometer Gyroscope&Yes&More than one&Wearable sensor&~97\%&Multiclass fall and ADL detection.&  High initial cost, separate device, no local processing on device.\\
Yu, Gong, and Kollias (2017)&Camera&Yes&More than one&Image and computer vision&~96\%&Posture based detection ( Laying is treated as fall).&High initial cost, no local processing on device, not suitable for outdoor, privacy issues.\\

Juang et al.(2015)&Camera&Yes&More than one&Image and computer vision&100\%&Human joint identification along with fall.&High initial cost, no local processing on device,low portability, not suitable for outdoor, privacy issues. No local dataset used.\\

Zhang et al.(2020)& Camera& Yes&More than one&Image and computer vision& ~98\%&Fall detection based on body posture, local dataset used.&High initial cost, no local processing on device, not suitable for outdoor.\\

Shu, Francy. et al.(2021)&Camera&Yes&More than one& Image and computer vision&94\%&Multi genre fall detection using eight cameras.&High initial cost,low portability, no local processing on device, not suitable for outdoor, privacy issues.\\

\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable*}

\end{document}
```

I used article here as the svjour class isn't in the standard distributions, but the same would work with any class.

Comment: I have shared the template in OP. It will be very kind of you if you can test this code by creating two dummy pages and inserting the table between two. Thanks in advance, Can we align the accuracy % as center just for a better look?

Comment: @Bukaida two -colunm floats always go to the _next_ page so you just need to put the table at a suitable point in teh source soi it comes on the oage you need.

Answer (score 1):

With use of the `tabularx` for table, `makcell` for column headers, table rules and additional vertical space.  For text align in cells is used `ragged2e` package:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{ragged2e}           % <--- new
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx} % <--- new
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
    
\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaystable}
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
\caption{Comparison among state of the art designs}
\label{tab:1}       % Give a unique label
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{L|L c >{\hsize=0.6\hsize}L 
                                   >{\hsize=0.6\hsize}L  c L 
                                   >{\hsize=1.8\hsize}L }
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
\thead{Reference}   
    & \thead{Sensors}
        & \thead{Dedicated}
            & \thead{Number of\\ sensors}
                & \thead{Method}
                    & \thead{Accuracy}
                        & \thead{Features}
                            & \thead{Limitations}   \\
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
Er and Tan (2018)&Sound sensor, accelerometer&Yes&More than one&Non-ambulatory&~92\%&Fuzzy logic based dual detection capability&Indoor only, no location information, costly and non-portable solution.\\

He et al.(2020)&RFID and Radar&Yes&More than one&Non-ambulatory&~94\%&Increased detection area up to 230\% compared to traditional systems.&Indoor only, no location information, costly and non-portable solution. Implementation requires specialized training.\\

Van Thanh et al.(2018)&Proprietary accelerometer&Yes&One&Wearable sensor&~92\%&Fall as well as post fall posture recognition.&Costly and bulky, no local processing on device, no text based warning SMS.\\

Zhang, Hongtao et al.(2020)&Accelerometer, Gyroscope and Magnetometer&Yes&More than one&Wearable
sensor&~96\%&Fall and post fall posture recognition. Warning SMS with location.&Costly and bulky, no local processing on device, no text based warning SMS.\\

Zurbuchen, N. et al.(2021)&Accelerometer Gyroscope&Yes&More than one&Wearable sensor&~97\%&Multiclass fall and ADL detection.&  High initial cost, separate device, no local processing on device.\\
Yu, Gong, and Kollias (2017)&Camera&Yes&More than one&Image and computer vision&~96\%&Posture based detection ( Laying is treated as fall).&High initial cost, no local processing on device, not suitable for outdoor, privacy issues.\\

Juang et al.(2015)&Camera&Yes&More than one&Image and computer vision&100\%&Human joint identification along with fall.&High initial cost, no local processing on device,low portability, not suitable for outdoor, privacy issues. No local dataset used.\\

Zhang et al.(2020)& Camera& Yes&More than one&Image and computer vision& ~98\%&Fall detection based on body posture, local dataset used.&High initial cost, no local processing on device, not suitable for outdoor.\\

Shu, Francy. et al.(2021)&Camera&Yes&More than one& Image and computer vision&94\%&Multi genre fall detection using eight cameras.&High initial cost,low portability, no local processing on device, not suitable for outdoor, privacy issues.\\
        \Xhline{1.2pt}
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]